# Javascript/Jquery sequence not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

This is probably a very basic question. It's my first time trying to use JQuery on a website. This is the markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/etchy.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="grid"></div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I am just trying to test this thing out at the moment.

```
alert("meh");
var i = 0;
while (i < 16) {

    $('#wrapper').append("<div class="grid"></div>");
    i += 1;
}
```

My problem is that if I erase everything except for the alert() statement, it works fine, so the script definitely gets loaded, but if I add in the rest not even the alert() works anymore, which just doesn't make any sense to me. I am trying to make a grid of divs on the page, but that is a bit irrelevant at the moment, I am just trying to figure out why this strange behaviour. Originally I was going to use $(document).ready(function(){}); but now I am just trying to get anything to work. Anybody have an idea what is going on here, why is nothing working at all?
Sorry for the n00b question, thanks for your help in advance guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either escape the quotes or use single quotes instead in this line `$('#wrapper').append("<div class="grid"></div>");`

---

This won't work:

```
$('#wrapper').append("<div class="grid"></div>"); //<--double quotes not escaped
```

This will work:

```
$('#wrapper').append("<div class=\"grid\"></div>"); //<--escaped
```

This will work:

```
$('#wrapper').append("<div class='grid'></div>"); //<--alternate quotes
```

---

This won't work:

```
$('#wrapper').append('<div class='grid'></div>'); //single quotes not escaped
```

This will work:

```
$('#wrapper').append('<div class=\'grid\'></div>'); //single quotes escaped
```

This will work:

```
$('#wrapper').append('<div class="grid"></div>'); //alternate quotes
```

---

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/b3fxC/) is a fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, cheers. That was definitely the problem. Once I figured out you get JS errors in the devtools console, I realized I forgot to escape them.

Comment: Right on. Yeah - those dev tools are nice. If my answer has helped, please accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

alert isn't JQuery-dependent, so that isn't a good way to test if the JQuery script is loaded. If you're using Chrome, right-click the site and click "Inspect element" and click on the src url of your JQuery script to see if it's loaded correctly.

Comment: Cool, thanks. There is something wrong with my script the divs don't get added yet, but your suggestion of using the DevTools made me realize there's error messages in the JS console :D. The second set of quotation marks weren't escaped that's why it didn't run. The alert() comes up now, so at least something is happening. Cheers.

Comment: By the way, what would I see if a script wouldn't be loaded? There is nothing errory when I do Inspect Elements. (I use Iceweasel, but the devtools would probably be the same as for Firefox)

Comment: You'd see no code if the script isn't loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

a few problems i've noticed

- Your last line in the while should be `i++;`. This is the common way you increment any `Number`. Though as the comments corrected my original answer, both will do the same.
- also, in your append, wrap the div with single quotes. See how "grid" is black, that means you have closed the string. Using single quotes will allow you to properly add that grid class.

as a side note, a more common pattern than using while (I didn't even know javascript had while lol) is the for loop.

```
for(var i=0; i < 16; i++){

}
```

I'm unsure of performance at this small of scale would matter between `while` and `for` but to me looks cleaner and as I said before, is more common practice.

Another thing to check would be if jQuery is indeed loading properly. Let me know if you find any of this helps!

Comment: i++ and i+=1 are exactly the same. if in doubt run `var i = 0; while(i < 12){i+=1;} console.log("i: " + i);` in console

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. The non-escaped quotes around grid were a horrible mistake, I corrected them and the alert() comes up now at least. Any idea how I can check if JQuery loads or not? The script runs now as I said, because there are no more syntax errors, but the new divs don't get created like I wanted.